# Civimail tracked links seem to be broken in 4.6.8

Tags: civimail, drupal, issues, 4.6.8

Links within both old (prior to update to 4.6.8) and new promo emails are not working at all.
Resulting in something like this:
The requested page "/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/url.php?u=2698&qid=78621" could not be found.

(Also, when I view the mailing in a browser there is no qid at all, but I assume that the qid is the recipient and the u is the URI?)

Comment: Not sure how I could help you. But it might help if you could find out if this problem is only on your site but also on other sites (e.g. the demo or a fresh install).

Comment: I used the demo, which is 4.6.9 and looked at an HTML preview page and the link I created worked. So I guess something in my install is broken, but I have no idea how to start trying to find them problem! There is a table of links (civicrm_mailing_trackable_url) which seems to have everything from prior to and since the upgrade and looks in perfect order. My install did go a bit screwy during the recent upgrade process, resulting in some server 500 errors, but I seem to have resolved everything.

Comment: Based on the post here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2421/why-do-track-click-through-links-not-redirect-to-correct-address?rq=1 I checked permissions on /sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/url.php. I found the file owner (for everything from this install) is 1031:1031 so I tried changing that to the actual website's username. The file permission was already 644, which appears to make sense to me. No improvement. Tried 777 and still no improvement so put back to 644.